# How can a Python 2.7 string be interpreted as an integer like in C char array?

Tags: python, c, arrays, python-2.7, endianness

In C, a character array could be referenced by an `int *` or cast to be interpreted as an integer value. Here's a small example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   char *str = "AABB";
   int *i = (int *)str;
   printf("int value: %d\n", *i);
   return 0;
}
```

This outputs `int value: 1111638337` which is 0x42424141.

How can I achieve this in Python 2.7? I know I could use ord() and then shift left, but I figure there has the be a better solution than this. Also, if there is a way to adjust endianness that would be helpful too.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?  It seems like you should be using something like `bytearray` instead of a string.

Comment: @0x5453 I'm trying to reverse a toy-level hashing algorithm written in C, this is really an exercise more than anything. I'm trying to use it to learn more about Python since I'm used to some more low-level features that C has. I think you're right and it should be converted to a byte array.

Comment: Doing this is a bad idea in C, and is sometimes undefined behavior, even with the special case for `char` in the strict aliasing rules - it's okay to access an object of effective type `int` through a `char *`, but accessing an object of effective type `char` through an `int *` is still UB.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica You're correct, it just happens to be what that algorithm does.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `struct` module to interpret byte sequences as C-style data types:

```
import struct
hex(struct.unpack("i", "AABB")[0])
```

That gives `'0x42424141'`.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was hoping for!